# mysql, select two different rows with same id but different values in another column

Tags: mysql, join, rows

Preemptive apology for the title there... wasn't sure what to put....

I am not the best with mysql and I have a problem that I am not able to wrap my head around.

I have one table....which is the metadata table for a wordpress site...
In the table I am storing the FB like count and the permalink for each post.... so it looks something like this for one post...

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
| meta_id     |    post_id     |     meta_key    |            meta_value            |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|           1 |      446       |    _fb_count    |                 2                |
|           2 |      446       |    _permalink   | /2013/08/image-aligned-left/446/ |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

What I would like to do is query this table and return both these values so that the returned data would be (post_id,Facebook Like Count, Permalink)... So it would look like:

```
+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|    post_id     |     _fb_count   |            _permalink            |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
|      446       |        2        | /2013/08/image-aligned-left/446/ |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

I looked around and am guessing I need to do some kind of inner join on the same table.... but I am not getting the results I want...

I tried something like this with no success:

```
SELECT pl.post_id,pl.meta_value,FBL.meta_value from wp_postmeta pl inner join wp_postmeta FBL on pl.post_id = FBL.post_id WHERE pl.meta_key = '_permalink' OR FBL.meta_key = '_fb_count
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: This is called a "pivot" or "crosstab", and has been answered here on SO many times.  Please do a search for these terms.

Comment: Actually you should be using [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) rather than querying the database directly.

Comment: @Rob... yes... I was using get_post_meta but..... in this particular instance... it is just easier to store it for my particular situation....

Comment: @Jim thanks for the lingo... I was not familiar with what it is called and that was a big factor in my searches coming up empty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use conditional aggregation for that

```
SELECT post_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_fb_count' THEN meta_value END) `_fb_count`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_permalink' THEN meta_value END) `_permalink`
  FROM wp_postmeta
 WHERE meta_key IN('_fb_count', '_permalink')
 GROUP BY post_id
```

Output:

```
| POST_ID | _FB_COUNT |                       _PERMALINK |
|---------|-----------|----------------------------------|
|     446 |         2 | /2013/08/image-aligned-left/446/ |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c410/1)** demo

But I agree with @Rob you probably better off using WP's appropriate functions for that.

Comment: Perfect!!! Much Appreciated... I'll have to dig into it later so I can understand why it works...

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

SELECT e.post_id, e.meta_value as _fb_count, m.meta_value as _permalink FROM `table` e  inner join 'table' m where e.meta_key = '_fb_count'  and  m.meta_key= '_permalink' and e.post_id= m.post_id